# How to modify Perl script to move packages in different directory based on version?

Tags: perl

I have this Perl script which is used to sort packages based on package version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# Compare versions of all *.rpm files against the
# latest packages installed (if installed)
#
# Usage:
# rpmver.pl
# This script looks for all *.rpm files.
#
use strict;
use RPM2;
my $rpm_db = RPM2->open_rpm_db();
for my $filename (<*.rpm>) {
    my $h = RPM2->open_package( $filename );
    # Ensure we compare against the newest
    # package of the given name.
    my ($installed) =
      sort { $b <=> $a } $rpm_db->find_by_name($h->name);
    if (not $installed) {
        printf "Package %s not installed.\n", $h->as_nvre;
    } else {
        my ($result) = ($h <=> $installed);
        if ($result < 0) {
            printf "Installed package %s newer than file %s\n",
            $installed->as_nvre,
            $h->as_nvre;
        } else {
            printf "File %s newer than installed package %s\n",
            $h->as_nvre,
            $installed->as_nvre;
        }
    }
 }
```

I have a Linux repository with SRPMs. I want to move the packages with the latest into different directory; for example `latest_packages`. How must the script be modified?

Comment: Is this something more tricky than creating a directory and copying files into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, store all the as-of-now-latest package names in a hash called `%latest_package`; then after checking all packages loop over the keys of the hash and move those latest packages.

```
} else {
    printf "File %s newer than installed package %s\n", ...
    $latest_package{$h->name} = $installed->as_nvre;
    ...
}
```

Use `File::Copy` module's `move()` method to move the files. Don't forget to treat it like any other IO system call (`die` if it errors out including contents of `$!` error text variable; or use `autodie`).

```
foreach my $name (sort keys %latest_package) {
    File::Copy::move($latest_package{$name}, $LATEST_PACKAGE_DIR) 
        || die "Could not move $latest_package{$name} to $LATEST_PACKAGE_DIR: $!);
}
```

Use `mkdir()` function to create the directory if needed.